# Send email via smtp using PHPMailer

Tags: email, smtp, phpmailer

I'm trying to send email using PHPMailer, adding a recipient to an outlook email and cc to a gmail email

I tried to change the Mailer to 'mail' but when I did I received 2 emails on the gmail and it's not working on the outlook email
One of the emails says

"This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:"

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

$toEmail = 'email@domain.com';
$cc =  "email@gmail.com";
$fromEmail = $_POST['email'];

$email = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
$email->IsSMTP();
$email->SMTPDebug = 2;
$email->Debugoutput = 'html';
$email->Mailer = "smtp";
$email->Host = "ex5.mail.ovh.net";
$email->Port = 587; // 8025, 587 and 25 can also be used. Use Port 465 for SSL.
$email->SMTPAuth = true;
$email->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$email->Username = "username";
$email->Password = "password";

//from is the email the user entered in the form

$email->SetFrom($_POST['email'], $name); //Name is optional
$email->Subject   = "Survey submitted by " . $name;
$email->Body      = $htmlContent;
$email->AddAddress($toEmail);
$email->isHTML(true);   
$file_to_attach = $_FILES;

$email->AddCC($cc);

$email->addAttachment($_FILES['0']['tmp_name'],
                     $_FILES['0']['name']);

$email->send();
echo 'Message has been sent';
}catch (Exception $e) {
   echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$email->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

In the network tab I'm receiving this message as an error

As the message shows, the conversation is going between intralogisoft host server & client (which is the hosting provider for the website) not between "ex5.mail.ovh.net" and client (the host I specified)

Which is probably a redirection to the host's server is what's happening under the hood and that's why the certificate verification is failing (comparing the certificate auth values with intralogisoft's certificate not with ex5.mail.ovh.net)

If this is the problem, what's could be the solution? And if this isn't the problem then what is it?

```
2023-02-26 16:30:15 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-hosting.intralogisoft.com ESMTP Exim 4.96 #2 Sun, 26 Feb 2023 16:30:15 +0000 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
2023-02-26 16:30:15 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO i-swissconsult.com
2023-02-26 16:30:15 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-hosting.intralogisoft.com Hello i-swissconsult.com [51.68.215.97]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-PIPECONNECT250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-STARTTLS250 HELP
2023-02-26 16:30:15 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2023-02-26 16:30:15 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Connection failed. stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
2023-02-26 16:30:15 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2023-02-26 16:30:15
2023-02-26 16:30:15
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Connection failed. stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Connection failed. stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1.
```

Comment: I suggest you read your ISP’s mail policy to find out how they want you to use email. Good that you spotted why verification is failing.

Comment: You seem to have trimmed the actually useful error indicator from the quoted bounce message.

Comment: @tripleee the only part I trimmed was this "OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failedSMTP server error: QUIT command failed Detail:" and after detail there's just signs

Comment: The part immediatey after _"A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:"_ would be important to include (maybe trim or obfuscate the failed addresses, but the actual error message is important).

Comment: @tripleee this message is sent to my email (gmail) when I replaced the mailer with 'mail' instead of smtp. And the message is only saying, it's not sent correctly to all parties with no other details, the email that failed is the email on "ex5.mail.ovh.net" host. And the part directly after failed is only the email address there's nothing else